# How do I verify in a Django unit test that my context contains a form object?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, view

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have this view ...

```
def get(request):
    context = {}
    if not request.GET:
        tax_calculator_form = TaxCalculatorForm()
    else:
        ...

    context['form'] = tax_calculator_form
    return render(request, "tax_calculator.html", context)
```

I want to write some kind of assertion in my unit test that verifies the model contains my form object.  How do I do that?  So far I have

```
# Simple test to verify we can get the tax form
def test_get_tax_form(self):
    response = self.client.get("/form")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "tax_calculator.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response has a [`context` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context) that contains the context used to render the template.

```
self.assertIn('form', response.context)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.  Unfortunately, this is giving me a "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not ContextList" error.

Comment: Sorry, had those the wrong way round (too much Ruby recently).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use *assertIn* but it's better to use *assertContains* .

```
self.assertContains(response, 'form', count=None, status_code=200, msg_prefix='', html=False)
```

This allow you to have more options and check status_code at the same time. for example set html to True to handle text as HTML. The comparison with the response content will be based on HTML semantics instead of character-by-character equality. more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/).